# Verifone Vx670 displaying with upper padding in pos LCD screen

Tags: verifone

I’m working on Verifone Vx670 Point OF Sale(POS) terminals but I have the following situation :-

I downloaded the same code to two “Verifone Vx670” POS terminals. The code should display a menu for the POS user using this code:-

```
#define DYNAMIC_ROW_SIZE    25
char caTemp[DYNAMIC_ROW_SIZE] = "";
g_RowCount = 8;
for (i = 0; i < 4 && i < g_RowCount; i++)
{           
    memset (caTemp, 0x00, sizeof(caTemp));
    memcpy (caTemp, &g_DISPLAY_DATA[((g_DISPLAY_INDEX * 4 + i) * DYNAMIC_ROW_SIZE)], DYNAMIC_ROW_SIZE);
    write_at(caTemp, strlen(caTemp), 21 - strlen(caTemp), (i*2)+2);
}
```

I find that one of POS terminals is displaying the menu well as shown in figure Vx670_Working.jpg
[Vx670_Working.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wikSl.jpg)

But the other one is display the menu with upper padding as shown in figure Vx670_Error.jpg

[Vx670_Error.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/srtnR.jpg)

I don’t know why the second terminal displaying this upper padding before the menu.

Can anyone please help me to figure out the issue

Comment: I have never worked with a terminal with the expanded screen such as the 670, but my first thought is that perhaps there is a backward compatibility toggle set somewhere in the second one that makes the screen behave like that of one of the standard 8 line terminals.  Check your config.sys and see if there is something there that could be making the display backward compatible.  Also verify that both terminals have the same OS and other supporting software. Please post back if you find the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.We have found that OS is different for two devices.How can I install the same OS to the defected terminal?

Comment: The best thing to do is to get an account on DevNet (http://www.verifonedevnet.com).  If you are developing on VeriFone, then you should have some VeriFone representative that can help you do that.  Heads up--they will likely require you to go through some official training courses or some nonsense like that, but maybe not... you'll just need to ask.